# angularjs table : tr with category using ng-repeat with list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

Given the following model :

```
[{categoryName: "category1", items:[{name:"item1.1"}{name:"item1.2"},...]}, 
 {categoryName: "category2", items:[{name:"item2.1"},...]},...]
```

I'd like to create this table :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>category1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>item1.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>item1.2</td>
  </tr>
  ...
  <tr>
    <th>category2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>item2.1</td>
  </tr>
  ...
 </table>
```

How would you do it using angularjs instructions ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nested repeats and the new `ng-repeat-start`/`ng-repeat-end` *and* remembering that it is OK for a `<table>` to have many bodies and heads:

```
<table>
    <thead ng-repeat-start="x in data">
        <tr><th>{{x.categoryName}}</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat-end>
        <tr ng-repeat="y in x.items">
            <td>{{y.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Relevant fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kGZt8/

Documentation: [ngRepeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat)

Comment: awesome, didn't knew about the ng-repeat-start/end statement.